# How do I search for emails in Outlook that have a link to a file on OneDrive?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email, office365, onedrive, microsoft-outlook-365

Before the days of online collaboration with Microsoft 365, people would attach files to emails and I used to include them in Outlook searches by using `hasattachments:yes`.

Now people send me links to files on OneDrive. As a result `hasattachments:yes` no longer works because they haven't actually attached anything.

Assuming I'm searching for `from:jones tps importance:high`, what can I append to this search so that I only get emails where a link to a OneDrive file has been provided?

Comment: Where is the link physically inside the message, is it just mentioned inside the text?

Comment: Search for the OneDrive link's site domain: `1drv.ms`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create a rule in Outlook that uses the condition of
"with specific words in the body" and that tags an email containing
a onedrive link with a category named for example "onedrive".

You may then search for it with the condition `category:onedrive`.

Comment: That's a pretty neat idea, thanks! The only (slight) downside is that that once someone posts a link then the entire conversation from that point onwards also gets tagged.

Comment: It would be if the link is included in the reply text. Doing better than that would require a VBA rule that can distinguish in which part of the email is included the link.

Comment: Yep, I'm debating about writing a small bit of VBA that takes an incoming email, scans only the first message part for the link and then categorises it accordingly. The downside is that I'll need to also code something extra to scan all my existing emails.

Comment: See [Run rules manually in Classic Outlook for Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-rules-in-new-and-classic-outlook-for-windows-8400435c-f14e-4272-9004-1548bb1848f2#ID0EBBF=Classic_Outlook).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Comment: @Soki: ????????

Comment: I'm sorry. It's your answer.